# android RadioButton text is not updated when RadioButton is selected in RadioGroup, and Fragment is recreated from backstack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a radiogroup where I programmatically add radiobuttons. This is all done in `onCreateView()` method, so should be redone every time fragment is recreated from the backstack. The problem I have is when I programmatically preselect the radiobutton at the start by using `RadioGroup.check(id)`, RadioButton text no longer updates on subsequent calls to `onCreateView()` method. Any ideas?

Project is using compatibility library (v4) if this makes any difference.

Here is the code:

```
public static String x; //(x changes every time)

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = nflater.inflate(R.layout.right, container, false);

    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    rg.removeAllViews();

    Log.d("Cild count", Integer.toString(rg.getChildCount()); // Always 0

    RadioButton.rb = new RadioButton(getActivity());

    // Always works first time. Does not work with 1 and 2 when fragment is recreated from back stack.
    rb.setText(x); 
    rb.setId(99099); // 1 Atbitrary int for id

    rg.addView(rb);
    rg.check(99099); // 2 Selection of radiobutton

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: everytime onCreateView is called, is the id you setting changed atleast?

Comment: @AmaJayJB yes, looks like the problem was with `rb.setId(990099)`. I removd it alltogether and it worked in the emulaor.

Comment: Awesome :) should I update the answer for it then? Also I don't think you have to entirely delete that line, you could increment a number each time and increase the id variable if you want? I could put that in the answer too?

Comment: Well, I tried it in a phone, and encountered the same error again. Bacically when you recreate an activity from the backstack it somehow does not repaint the view despite me invalidating it or forcing layout. I honestly believe there is a bug (or feature :)) in Android backstack implementation which caches the view and then does not repaint it. I solved the problem by not using the backstact, but instead replacing the layout manually through `FragmentTransaction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by not using a backstack, but instead manually handling onBackPressed.

```
Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragmentByTag("Fragment name");

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (fr != null)
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(container, new PreviousFragment, "Tag").commit();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```